# Localization Principle (SUSY)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, supersymmetry, path-integral, boundary-conditions

[Mirror Symmetry](https://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf) p.200/201

Last section p.200/first p.201

It says, that the localization principle would not work if one would not impose periodic boundary conditions for the fermion integration, cause there would not be a supersymmetry to begin with.

Can anyone explain why this is so? I somehow do not get that argument.

Answer (score 1):

The engine behind path integral localization is [SUSY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry). The issue is that in order for the infinitesimal SUSY transformation (10.165) on p. 199 to be well-defined, the right and left-hand sides of the eq. (10.165) must obey the same boundary condition (BC). Since the boson obeys periodic BC, the fermion must as well.